# Spring ElasticSearchTemplate UPDATE MultipleDocument

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-template

With Some Criteria or Query I would like to filter all ElasticSearch Documents and then Partial Update them

I am looking for `ElasticSearchTemplate` Alternative for `mongoTemplate.updateMulti(Query,Update,Class)`

Right now I am getting distinct IDs and Updating manually one by one via

```
private UpdateQuery updateExistingDocument(String Id) {
    // Add updatedDateTime, CreatedDateTime, CreateBy, UpdatedBy field in existing documents in Elastic Search Engine
    UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest().doc("UpdatedDateTime", new Date(), "CreatedDateTime", new Date(), "CreatedBy", "admin", "UpdatedBy", "admin");

    // Create updateQuery
    UpdateQuery updateQuery = new UpdateQueryBuilder().withId(Id).withClass(ElasticSearchDocument.class).build();
    updateQuery.setUpdateRequest(updateRequest);

    // Execute update
     elasticsearchTemplate.update(updateQuery);
}
```

How to do it in Bulk?

Comment: @Alon : Can you find Query or Criteria Filter in SO link you shared  ?. Thats Updating single document one by one. I want to filter by a criteria then apply update. How it could be possible duplicate ?

Comment: I am looking `ElasticSearch` alternative for `mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query,update,class);`